# How to create BinaryType Column using multiple columns of a pySpark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have recently started working with pySpark so don't know about many details regarding this.

I am trying to create a BinaryType column in a data frame? But struggling to do it...

for example, let's take a simple df

`df.show(2)`

```
+---+----------+
|  col1|col2|
+---+----------+
|  "1"| null|
|  "2"| "20"|
+---+----------+
```

Now I want to have a third column "col3" with BinaryType like

```
|  col1|col2| col3|
+---+----------+
|  "1"| null|[1 null]
|  "2"| "20"|[ 2 20]
+---+----------+
```

How should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [('1', None), ('2', '20')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, ['col1', 'col2'])
df.show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|null|
|   2|  20|
+----+----+



df = df.withColumn('col3', F.array(['col1', 'col2']))
df.show()


+----+----+-------+
|col1|col2|   col3|
+----+----+-------+
|   1|null|   [1,]|
|   2|  20|[2, 20]|
+----+----+-------+
```