# GEOMETRY ST_GeomFromWKB(binary wkb) on spark using Java Language

Tags: java, apache-spark, geospark

I have a dataframe with `Binary` column type :

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|BinaryGeometry                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[00 00 00 00 01 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 04 00 F0 00 DC CC 1A C0 87 14 01 81 1E 1B 41 40 FC FF EF 00 68 AA 1A C0 BF EE 57 20 85 19 41 40 04 00 F0 00 8C 86 1A C0 CC DC 8B DC AE 1A 41 40 FF FF EF 00 44 74 1A C0 CA 9D 5D 61 10 1C 41 40 FF FF EF 00 64 63 1A C0 BF 1F 98 0B 3A 1D 41 40 FF FF EF 00 44 47 1A C0 E4 6B A0 DD CE 1D 41 40 FC FF EF 00 D8 2B 1A C0 54 E4 71 67 6D 1C 41 40 FF FF EF 00 44 1A 1A C0 BF 1F 98 0B 3A 1D 41 40 02 00 F0 00 80 0B 1A C0 0D 80 00 13 2F 23 41 40 02 00 F0 00 B0 35 1A C0 CC F6 23 F8 BD 26 41 40 04 00 F0 00 0C 43 1A C0 73 1A 44 AF 16 26 41 40 02 00 F0 00 40 5A 1A C0 FF 54 9C 7C 2D 27 41 40 02 00 F0 00 50 68 1A C0 87 6E B9 42 44 28 41 40 02 00 F0 00 00 7C 1A C0 78 2B 85 BA F5 26 41 40 FC FF EF 00 18 91 1A C0 49 96 6F 58 C6 28 41 40 02 00 F0 00 B0 BC 1A C0 91 FA 4B 0E 7F 20 41 40 04 00 F0 00 DC CC 1A C0 87 14 01 81 1E 1B 41 40] |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to Convert the Well Known Binary wkb into a Geometry.

From my researsh I found that `ST_GeomFromWKB` function returns an `ST_Geometry` value, which is transformed from a `LONG BINARY` value containing the `Well Known Binary (WKB)` representation of an `ST_Geometry`.

I'm trying to apply that on my dataframe , But the `BinaryGeometry` column is a `Binary` type like an `Array[Byte]`.

My question is : how to get the `LONG BINARY` value from Binary column on spark ?

I tried `hex` function .

```
df.withColumn("BinaryGeometry",hex(col("BinaryGeometry")))
        .withColumn("BinaryGeometry",expr("ST_GeomFromWKB(BinaryGeometry)"))
```

I get the following output witch is not correct:

```
POINT (0 0)
```

**EDIT**

```
|-- BinaryGeometry: binary (nullable = true)
```

**See also**
http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/ST_GeomFromWKB/

Comment: can you print the schema for `BinaryGeometry` column?

Comment: please check my Edit

Comment: any sample code to create this column

Comment: check this ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636127/how-to-create-binarytype-column-using-multiple-columns-of-a-pyspark-dataframe

Comment: I loaded the data from a mysql table

Comment: which lib are you using? `geospark`?

Comment: yes ,I'm using  GeoSpark

Comment: do you have decimal value for this binary column

Comment: No , I have just the data mentioned

Comment: @Someshwar Kale , do you have any idea please ?

Comment: I found a problem close to mine since I take the data from mysql , but I didn't understand the issus. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60577841/13518708

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219340/discussion-between-melissa-maya-and-someshwar-kale).

Comment: check this example- https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/fcd3fd87d519603656fbf1755f40be388915a7af/sql/src/test/java/org/datasyslab/geosparksql/adapterTestJava.java#L158

Comment: Thank you , I tried that `Dataset<Row> dataaa = sparkSession.sql("select ST_GeomFromWKB(df.BinaryGeometry) as geomdata from df") ;` , But I get that :`java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String` , The problem is the type of my data

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem as following :

the problem is in the loading of the database table, we must use the following code:

```
Dataset <Row> df_zones =        sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url", "").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "(select ST_AsWKT(geom) as BinaryGeometry  from zones) as t").option("user", "root").option("password", "").load();
```